# Reactjs Antd library and google maps Places

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api, antd

My team and I have been using `Antd` a react component library. I was asked to connect `google.map`'s Places library to an input field so we can get an easy address drop-down list.

The problem is the `Antd`'s input component is wrapped up under the hood. So **when I click on an address from `google.maps` Places menu it appears in the input field for a milli sec then disappears**.

I tried all the `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopPropoagtion()`. Is there any trick to combining `google.maps` places returned data with a well nested react-ui component?

Comment: Any code about your implements?

Comment: Ok so I found one way to do it but I'm not sure it's the best way, I am using functional components so when I decided to try using a ref I saw that It was not functional component compatible, then I saw the useRef hook. I tried the useRef hook but had the same issue not being able to refference an actual HTML Element. Thats when I tried using a wrapper around the antD input element and created a ref there. Then I used the native children method on the new ref and was able to traverse down to the html input element inside the antd component.

Comment: const AddressField = () => {
 let wrapper = useRef(null);
 useEffect(() => {
    if(loadGoogleMapsApi) {
    const autoPlaces = loadGoogleMapsApi({
  key: `YOUR-KEY-HERE`,
   libraries: [`places`]
   });
  autoPlaces.then((data) => {
  new data.places.Autocomplete(
     wrapper.current.children[0],
      {
         types: ['geocode']
      }
      )
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }
    },[])
   return (
    <div ref={wrapper}>
       <Input
          id="addressField"
            type="text"
              />
        </div>
  )

Here is the antd component

Comment: what do you mean code "Any code about your implements?"

Comment: OK i see what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(too long for comment)

I have the exact same problem.
I'm using NextJS with functional component and [@react-google-maps/api](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/) library.

**The workaround I use:** simple `<input>` element combined with the right CSS class to make it look like the Antd `<Input>`.

Like this:

```
<LoadScript
    googleMapsApiKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY}
    libraries={libraries}
>
    <Autocomplete
        onLoad={(autocomplete) => setAutocomplete(autocomplete)}
        onPlaceChanged={onPlaceChanged}
        restrictions={{ country: "fr" }}
        fields={['geometry.location', 'formatted_address']}
    >
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your address"
            className="ant-input"
        />
    </Autocomplete>
</LoadScript>
```

This way, when clicking on an address from Places menu, its value stays in the input field.

If anyone has a better and less hacky solution, I'm looking for one!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple matter of state management. It sounds like the google-places input field was working correctly or it wouldn't have shown up at all. If your input field is connected to let's say Reactjs then you will need to add the google-places response data to your state-management and it should stop disappearing. This happens a lot when companies use custom state-management systems.